# adding an icon menu from another jsp file as a column to a datatable in liferay

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, datatable, liferay

[There are 2 tables here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2keQ.png)
The table below is using purely container to display populate the tables from database whereas the one above is using datatable.

However i wish to duplicate the last column of displaying a icon menu for edit and delete actions which is contained inside actions.jsp inside the table above.

**This is my partial code in view.jsp displaying the datatables.**

```
<%

List<Guestbook> guestbookList = GuestbookLocalServiceUtil.getGuestbooks(scopeGroupId);
request.setAttribute("guestbookList", guestbookList);
%>

  <table id="gbdb" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <c:forEach items="${guestbookList}" var="guestbook">
       <tr>
       <td>${guestbook.name}</td>
       <td>${guestbook.status}</td>
       <td><jsp:include page="${actions.jsp}" flush="true" /></td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**However as you can see my function of diplaying actions.jsp is not similar to the method for using container where i can just referenced the path using**

```
<td> <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
            align="right" 
            path="/guestbookadminportlet/guestbook_actions.jsp" /></td>
```

Please help me with the correct way of displaying by referencing to actions.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You should not include whole jsp as an action column if using jQuery data-table,

Let's assume you need to add Delete book action so your td should be replace by following code.

```html
<td> 
  <portlet:actionURL name="<%=DELETE_BOOK%>" var="deleteBookUrl">     
  <portlet:param name="bookId" value="${book.id}"/>                
  </portlet:actionURL> 
  <input type="button" onclick="location.href='${deleteBookUrl}'" value="Delete"/> 
</td>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: mind explaining to me the fields? ; where do you derive the var="deleteBookUrl" ad location.href=${deleteBookUrl}?

Comment: "deleteBookUrl" is not field it's a variable name for the action, please google on how to create render/action urls in liferay.